# Guava library not working with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, runtime, guava

My IDEA 10.5.2 hilights all guava (10.0.1) classes with error (no class found). But code is compilling correctly. I have this trouble only with guava jar's. Other jar's warks correctly.

I try to change guava version and jdk version (1.6, 1.7) and idea version but there is no result.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give more detail on the error message?

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ's indexes must not be seeing the class files, even if javac is. Depending on how your project is set up, your build process may have a different classpath than IntelliJ's indexes. At least as likely, though, is simply the presence of some corrupt entry in IntelliJ's indexes. Either way, do the following:

1. From the "Project Structure" dialog (in the File menu), go to the Libraries screen and ensure that the guava jar or its parent folder is listed in one of your libraries
2. In the same dialog's Modules screen, ensure that the above library is listed in your module.
3. Exit the dialog and click File -> Invalidate Caches.
4. Restart IntelliJ. This might take awhile.

With the information given, I can't be sure this is your problem, but it's always the steps I go through when a library mysteriously stops working (which happens more often than I'd like...).

Answer (score 0):

[Answering this old question as I came across this situation even in Idea Community Edition 2019.3.1]

For me it had been due to a change in the version of the library in the build.gradle file, and the solution was to recreate the project in a fresh folder

---

(or maybe I could've deleted some .idea or cache folders).

It mainly depends on the version of the library in the build.gradle file.

In my case, at first, the version of the library referred to was an earlier version and everything worked fine.

```
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: 'r05'
```

Later, had to use a newer version of the library and some classes in this new version.

```
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '23.5-jre'
```

Since build.gradle was updated, the project built fine as a gradle task.

IntelliJ hadn't got updated - though usually it does after a change in the gradle file.

Even after trying to mess around with File->Project Structure, and File->Invalidate Cache and Restart, etc... it hadn't worked, and finally recreating the project seemed to be a good workaround.